# SQL statement to get largest ID from database column

Tags: sql, database

I have an ID column which it supposed to set to auto-increment but I forgot to set in when creating the database. Let's say the ID is from 1 - 20. I used the select Max() Sql statement to get the largest ID:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table_Name;
```

It supposed to return me 20. However, it returns me 9. I also realized that the id column in database is jumbled up. It starts from 1,2 then skips to 9,10 - 20 then back to 3 - 8. And 8 appears to be the last row and I think that's where the 9 comes from. My id in database is varchar() data type.

So, is there any way to amend my Sql statement to get the largest id in a list of sorted id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `Select top 1 * from Table Order by ID desc`?

Comment: What database server (RDBMS) are you using?

Comment: this will always prove to be problematic in a long run when you will have many hits on the table. The max id would not work correctly. I say create a new identity column. Copy the previous data into the new one & you are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Table ORDER BY Convert(INT, id) DESC
```

Comment: Oh ya thanks a lot. But since id is integer, this should be the correct one: Select top 1 * from dbo.DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems Order by Convert(INT, id) desc

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely that the ID column is a varchar field, so 9 is greater than 10.

```
select max(convert(int, id)) from Table
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks alot. I totally forget about it's sorted in string. It works now

Answer (score 1):

Your column is a *character* type, not a *numeric* type, which explains everything you're seeing.

Try casting it to numeric:

```
select max(cast(id as signed)) from table
```

You haven't said which database you are using, so the syntax may vary to achieve the cast - consult online docs for your database.